# How to access metadata "source_url" from a chef recip?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to be able to include the `source_url` attribute from the `metadata.rb` file of my chef repository, but I can't figure out how to access this information from a Chef recipe.

Anyone did that before and could tell me how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html):

> The contents of the metadata.rb file provides information that helps Chef Infra Client and Server correctly deploy cookbooks to each node.

from what i know, there is no way (at least not straightforward one) to access the `metadata.rb` during the chef-client run.

but... during chef-client run, cookbooks are being synchronized and stored locally on the node's filesystem. that implies that you could implement a mechanism to read the `metadata.rb` file in your recipe (but i would not recommend doing so, i would definitely offer you to set a node attribute (or a data bag item) with the value(s) that you need during the chef-client run)